# Creating dummy variables indicating whether IDs occur within monthly data

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr, reshape

I have a dataframe that is formatted as follows:

```
    id       date
1    1 2021-07-06
2    2 2021-07-10
3    4 2021-07-14
4    5 2021-07-18
5    8 2021-07-22
6   10 2021-07-26
7   11 2021-07-30
8    1 2021-08-03
9    2 2021-08-07
10   3 2021-08-11
11   5 2021-08-15
12   8 2021-08-19
13   9 2021-08-23
14  10 2021-08-27
15  12 2021-08-31
16   1 2021-09-04
17   3 2021-09-08
18   4 2021-09-12
19   6 2021-09-16
20   7 2021-09-20
21   8 2021-09-24
```

and I am looking to create a new data frame with a row for each ID that contains dummy variables indicating whether or not it appears in each month in the first data frame, resulting in the following:

```
    id jul aug sep
1    1   1   1   1
2    2   1   1   0
3    3   0   1   1
4    4   1   0   1
5    5   1   1   0
6    6   0   0   1
7    7   0   0   1
8    8   1   1   1
9    9   0   1   0
10  10   1   1   0
11  11   1   0   0
12  12   0   1   0
```

How might I do this? Here is code to generate the first data frame:

```
> dput(df_start)
structure(list(id1 = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 
9, 10, 12, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8), date = structure(c(18814, 18818, 
18822, 18826, 18830, 18834, 18838, 18842, 18846, 18850, 18854, 
18858, 18862, 18866, 18870, 18874, 18878, 18882, 18886, 18890, 
18894), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Comment: Does 1 mean "one or more appearances", or should it be a count which in the current data just happens to be zero or one?

Comment: Is it possible an id could have more than one observation in a month? If so, what should happen?

Comment: only one ID per month in this scenario. I removed all non-unique IDs each month bc I was only interested in whether or not they appeared for my analysis; not how frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the month and then `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df%>%
  mutate(date=format(date, "%b"),
         value=1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=date,
              values_fn = sum, # in case an id has >1 per mo
              values_fill=0)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
     id1   Jul   Aug   Sep
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     1     1     0
 3     4     1     0     1
 4     5     1     1     0
 5     8     1     1     1
 6    10     1     1     0
 7    11     1     0     0
 8     3     0     1     1
 9     9     0     1     0
10    12     0     1     0
11     6     0     0     1
12     7     0     0     1
```

Comment: Is it possible an id could have more than one observation in a month? This will then output a list.

Comment: I guess we can sum the counts instead of ```value =1```. I will edit it later.

Comment: @JonSpring Nice edits! I was think about ```reframe(value=n())``` but ```value_fn=sum``` is certainly cleaner :-)

Comment: Or maybe `max` better here if we want multiple observations in a month to count as 1.

Comment: much appreciated. I was on the right track with the date variable I was generating, but I couldn't figure out the second two arguments of pivot_wider()

Answer (score 1):

You could convert date to month using `lubridate::month` when going from long to wide in `data.table::dcast`. In the event an id appears more than once per month, you can use a helper function to return 1 if length > 0.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

setDT(df_start)

id_exists = function(id) { if(length(id) > 0) 1 else 0 }

df_start = dcast(
  df_start, 
  id1 ~ month(date, label = T, abbr = T), 
  fun.aggregate = id_exists
)

    id1 Jul Aug Sep
 1:   1   1   1   1
 2:   2   1   1   0
 3:   3   0   1   1
 4:   4   1   0   1
 5:   5   1   1   0
 6:   6   0   0   1
 7:   7   0   0   1
 8:   8   1   1   1
 9:   9   0   1   0
10:  10   1   1   0
11:  11   1   0   0
12:  12   0   1   0
```